# Error while calculating drawdown in R

Tags: r, quantmod, quantitative-finance

I am using this code for backtesting

```
library(quantmod)
library(PerformanceAnalytics)

s <- get(getSymbols('SPY'))["2012::"]
s$sma20 <- EMA(Cl(s) , 20)
s$position <- ifelse(Cl(s) > s$sma20 , 1 , -1)
myReturn <- lag(s$position) * dailyReturn(s)
charts.PerformanceSummary(cbind(dailyReturn(s),myReturn))

Performance <- function(x) {

  cumRetx = Return.cumulative(x)
  annRetx = Return.annualized(x, scale=252)
  sharpex = SharpeRatio.annualized(x, scale=252)
  winpctx = length(x[x > 0])/length(x[x != 0])
  annSDx = sd.annualized(x, scale=252)

  DDs <- findDrawdowns(x)
  maxDDx = min(DDs$return)
  maxLx = max(DDs$length)

  Perf = c(cumRetx, annRetx, sharpex, winpctx, annSDx, maxDDx, maxLx)
  names(Perf) = c("Cumulative Return", "Annual Return","Annualized Sharpe Ratio",
                  "Win %", "Annualized Volatility", "Maximum Drawdown", "Max Length Drawdown")
  return(Perf)
}
cbind(STRAT=Performance(myReturn),BMK=Performance(dailyReturn(s)))
```

And I am using **performance function** which i got from internet to find sharpe, drawdown etc. After running this script I  am getting this error

```
Error in if (drawdowns[1] >= 0) priorSign = 1 else priorSign = 0 : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed 
7 findDrawdowns(x) at 2.R#18
6 Performance(myReturn) 
5 cbind(STRAT = Performance(myReturn), BMK = Performance(dailyReturn(s))) at 2.R#27
4 eval(expr, envir, enclos) 
3 eval(ei, envir) 
2 withVisible(eval(ei, envir)) 
1 source("~/Rtest/test/test.R", echo = TRUE) 
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In to_period(xx, period = on.opts[[period]], ...) :
  missing values removed from data
2: In to_period(xx, period = on.opts[[period]], ...) :
  missing values removed from data
```

Any idea how to solve this error and can you explain why it happened?

Comment: You have a missing value in `myReturn`, at date `2012-01-31`. `Performance(myReturn[-1])` works.

Comment: @Pascal thanks so because of the presence of NA caused this problem